# javascript and php variable mixup

Tags: javascript, php

Why will this code not work?

```
<?php
    $var = '<script type="text/javascript">
            var displayStr = "";
            switch(window.orientation)
            {
                case 0:
                    displayStr += "mobile";
                break;
                case -90:
                    displayStr += "mobile";
                break;
                case 90:
                    displayStr += "mobile";
                break;
                case 180:
                    displayStr += "mobile";
                break;

                default:
                    displayStr += "steddy";
            }
            document.write(displayStr);
        </script>';

    if($var == "steddy") {
        echo 'non rotatable';
    } elseif($var == "mobile") {
        echo 'rotatable';
    }
?>
```

Yes yes I know this is not the best way to do this but I just can't see why this shouldn't work.
If you just echo the $var it will show it just fine, but the "if" does not recognize it.
Pls help...

Comment: PHP is a server-side language - it does all its work on the server. Javascript is a client-side language - it does its work in your browser. You **cannot** mix the two like this.

Comment: what is the use of this
 if($var == "steddy") {
        echo 'non rotatable';
    } elseif($var == "mobile") {
        echo 'rotatable';
    }

Comment: @winterblood `Javascript is a client-side language` To be fair, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: It was for determining if the device viewing the content is rotatable (iPhone ect..) so you could make it load deferent content for each type.. Its a heavy site so it would be nice just to load the content needed on a mobile device..

Comment: @admdrew Yes, it can be, but it is not in the example provided above.

Comment: @winterblood Yeah, totally.

Comment: The only way (I know of) to detect mobile browsers in PHP is by user-agent sniffing, potentially with some additional HTTP header checking as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got here is javascript code inside of a PHP string. That code is not executed, it's just some text as far as PHP is concerned.

The proper use model for these two languages in this setup is: Server runs PHP first, client (browser) runs javascript second. Unfortunately, you can't just inject javascript into the middle of PHP and have it work.

Comment: That explains a lot.. Thanks.. - Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 0):

Well... This did the trick.

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE[rotatable] != "nope" && $_COOKIE[rotatable] != "yes") {
    if($_POST[rotatable] == "") { 
        echo '
            <form method="post" action="test.php" name="setType">
                <input type="hidden" name="rotatable" id="screen" value="">
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    var displayStr = "";
                    switch(window.orientation)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            displayStr += "yes";
                        break;
                        case -90:
                            displayStr += "yes";
                        break;
                        case 90:
                            displayStr += "yes";
                        break;
                        case 180:
                            displayStr += "yes";
                        break;
                        default:
                            displayStr += "nope";
                    }
                    var s = document.getElementById("screen");
                    s.value = displayStr;
                </script>
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    document.setType.submit();
                </script>
            </form>
         ';
    } elseif($_POST[rotatable] == "nope") {
        setcookie("rotatable", "nope", time()+3600);
        header("location: test.php");
    } elseif($_POST[rotatable] == "yes") {
        setcookie("rotatable", "yes", time()+3600);
        header("location: test.php");
    }
}

// Here comes the content of the site.


if($_COOKIE[rotatable] == "nope") {
    echo 'non rotatable';
} elseif($_COOKIE[rotatable] == "yes") {
    echo 'rotatable';
}
?>
```

Bud thanks to your all..